# Determine whether the list element is an calendar month

Tags: python, date, datetime

```
j_list = ['apple', 'mango', 'march', 'car', 'april', 'ocean']
```

While iterating the above list, I need to find whether the list element is a month or not.

Comment: What have you tried? Did it work partially or not at all? What are your sticking points?

Comment: Check calendar.month_name https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name

Answer (score 2):

`calender` module is useful for your question.

```
from calendar import month_name
months = {m.lower() for m in month_name[1:]} #list of months in lowercase
j_list = ['apple', 'mango', 'march', 'car', 'april', 'ocean']
for element in j_list:
    print(f'{element} : {element in months}') # result of checking is printed in boolean type
```

Here is the result:

```
apple : False
mango : False
march : True
car : False
april : True
ocean : False
```

Answer (score 1):

**A solution without using `import`'s :**

Create a list with the month names, and iterate through `j_list`, checking if the element is in the first list.

```
month_names = ['january', 'february' ... 'december']
for el in j_list:
    print(el, ':', el in month_names)
```

**Note:** It's faster than with `import` because: `import` itself can take time; and the `calendar.month_name` has one empty string (the first element), so it's a bit slower, and much slower for *giant* lists like `j_list`.